# Webix Grouplist. How return to previously opened state?

Tags: javascript, webix

I'm using webix grouplist in order to show some hierarchical data. And after dataset changed, I need to return state of the grouplist to previously opened condition.
I found the way how to save open state - getOpenState(), but seemed like in their API have no method something like setOpenState().
This is method for get open state:

```
webix.ui({
    view:"grouplist",
    data:[ //hierarchical JSON dataset
        {id:"root", value:"Films data", open:true, data:[
            { id:"1", open:true, value:"The Shawshank Redemption", data:[
                { id:"1.1", value:"Part 1" },
                { id:"1.2", value:"Part 2", data:[
                    { id:"1.2.1", value:"Page 1" },
                    { id:"1.2.2", value:"Page 1" }
                    ]},
                { id:"1.3", value:"Part 3" }
            ]},
            { id:"2", open:true, value:"The Godfather", data:[
                { id:"2.1", value:"Part 1" }
            ]}
        ]}
});


var state = $$('grouplist1').getOpenState();
if(state){
    result = JSON.stringify(state);
    webix.message(result);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solution was quite easy:
1. Get item id on click.

```
onItemClick: function (id, e, node) {
            setTimeEntry(this.getItem(id));
            webix.storage.local.put("id", id);
        }
```

2. Show item by using method .showItem(id)

```
    onAfterLoad: function () {
                this.hideOverlay();
                checkOptions();
                var itemId = webix.storage.local.get("id");
                if (itemId !== null && itemId !== undefined)
                this.showItem(itemId);
     }
```